# Generic type guards based on comparison

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
interface FruitMap {
  apple: string;
  orange: number;
}

interface FruitValue<T extends keyof FruitMap > {
  type: T;
  value: FruitMap[T];
}

const processFruitValue = (fruitValue: FruitValue<keyof FruitMap>) => {
  if (example.type === 'apple') {
    // example.value should be string, but it's string | number
  } else if (example.type === 'orange') {
    // example.value should be number, but it's string | number
  }
}
```

How can I get TypeScript to properly infer the value of `FruitMap` in `processFruitValue` ? It seems as it should be able to infer it based on having the key in the interface, but apparently now.

Comment: Should `TypeMap` be `FruitMap`, and by `getFruitValue` do you mean `processFruitValue`? Please check and edit so that it's a [mcve].

Comment: Something like `const processFruitValue = <T extends keyof FruitMap>(fruitValue: FruitValue<T>) => {` ?

Comment: You did not share `TypeMap` type

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the implementation of the `processFruitValue` function,
it looks like you want `FruitValue` to be a "discriminating union" type.

Therefore `FruitValue` cannot be an `interface`, but instead needs to be a "union type".

The solution I came up with was to use a "conditional type" that:

- maps the keys of FruitMap to an object type literal `{ type: T; value: FruitMap[T] }`.

This it the code of my solution:

```
interface FruitMap {
  apple: string;
  orange: number;
}

type FruitValue<T> = T extends keyof FruitMap ? { type: T; value: FruitMap[T] } : never;

const processFruitValue = (fruitValue: FruitValue<keyof FruitMap>) => {
  if (fruitValue.type === 'apple') {
    // %inferred-type: { type: 'apple'; value: string }
  } else if (fruitValue.type === 'orange') {
    // %inferred-type: { type: 'apple'; value: number }
  }
};
```